# How to convert/escape HTML in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel, html-escape-characters

[image]

^ Above is what `term.search_preview` renders in my templates.

Current HTML:

```
<div class="term-context-preview" value="{{term.term}}">
     <p ng-bind-html="term.search_preview">
         {{term.search_preview}}
     </p>
</div>
```

I have `'$sce'` injected into my controller:

```
.controller('TermsCtrl',
           ['$scope',
            '$sce',
            'TermsFactory',
            function($scope,
                     $sce,
                     TermsFactory) {

//vm.terms = is the terms array of objects that gets repeated in my widgets
vm.terms = TermsFactory.getTermsModel();
```

This is where term.search_preview comes from, vm.terms is an array of hundreds of objects. An example of one of the objects:

```
0: {
    id: 1,
    term: 'term',
    search_preview: 'dsjfdsjkl dsfjdsk fjdksf dksj fdksj '
}
```

Tried this:

```
// Build terms widgets with ng-repeat:
vm.terms = $sce.getTrustedHtml(TermsFactory.getTermsModel());
console.log(vm.terms);
```

**Error I'm getting:**
*[Error: [$sce:unsafe] Attempting to use an unsafe value in a safe context.](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$sce/unsafe)*

Comment: Is there any reason why you're permitting HTML through that property?  It makes sense to have the data back there, but the HTML is strictly a UI concern.

Comment: @Makoto Hmm, that's the data that I'm getting, it's how it was sent, is there a way to treat it as valid HTML rather than text?

Comment: The scary thing with that is that you could potentially see someone pass a `<script>` block through, which is technically valid HTML.  I'll root around a bit, but it doesn't seem like this would be a best practice to permit.

Comment: the safe html is stored in `context`, but you use `ng-bind-html="term.search_preview"`... Also, what do you intend ng-model to do on a `<p>`?

Comment: So now, what is the value of `term.search_preview`? Is it initialized with `$sce.trustAsHtml(something)`?

Comment: @JBNizet I updated my question with the object, which is inside and array, how would I bind trustAsHtml to just that attribute of the object?

Comment: by writing a for loop that does `obj.trustedSearchPreview =  $sce.trustAsHtml(obj.search_preview)` for each object?

Comment: Ya sorry had to run out... This did solve my problem! I had to use a factory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside of my termsFactory (where I process and save data objects from a JSON GET call)

I looped through them and used `$sce` there to created strings that were `trustAsHTML`

**TermsController:**

```
// Set terms into data model:
TermsFactory.setTermsModel(data.data.ticker_tags);

// Build tag widgets with ng-repeat:
vm.terms      = TermsFactory.getTermsModel();
vm.totalTerms = vm.terms.length;

console.log(vm.terms);
```

**TermsFactory:** (This is used to iterate through an object, turn items into **strings** and feed back into the object to be returned)

```
// Set data to terms:
var setTermsModel = function(data) {

    for (var i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        data[i].search_preview = $sce.trustAsHtml(data[i].search_preview);
    };

    terms = data;
    return terms;
};
```

**Then in the HTML files, fixed the output using** `ng-bind-html`**:**

```
<p ng-bind-html="term.search_preview">{{term.search_preview | filter:term.search_preview : limitTo : 200}}</p>

<section ng-show="context" ng-bind-html="context" class="term-context">
    <p>{{context}}</p>
</section>
```